# Groovy - Check last character & if append on condition

Tags: groovy

This is an idomism question regarding groovy - what is the simplest way to check the last char of a String and if present not append it to a modified String?

For example in Java you could do some like this;

```
String url = "http://www.google.com"

        //check to see if url already has / at the end
        if (url.charAt(url.size()-1)=='/')
            url =url + "Media"
        else
            url = "/Media"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
​def url = 'http://test.com/'
url += url?.endsWith('/') ? 'Media' : '/Media'

//This should work as well but it would throw an
//ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException if url is empty ('')
//url += url[-1] == '/' ? 'Media' : '/Media'

println url​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: Nice. I was going to suggest `url += url[-1] == '/' ? 'Media' : '/Media'`, but yours is more readable using `endsWith()`.

Comment: Yea, I thought of adding that but for `''`, you would get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException`. I should also include a null safe operator with `endsWith()`. Updated my answer anyways, thanks. ;)